# what is exceptional ratio for twitter card image

Tags: aspect-ratio, twitter-card

I am adding twitter cards meta tag.
I have tried this by adding dynamic
values for twitter meta tags.
I have page which having twitter card image as large in size like width:720 & height:960.

when i check with twitter card validator then image not get resize it looks bad.

Then i google and found that twitter card will not be cropped image unless they have an exceptional aspect ratio.

what is exceptional ratio ?
How can i find out exceptional ratio for image and use that image as twitter card image meta tag ?